# What does "low ceremony" mean?

Tags: terminology, trac

In the Trac Main Features page https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFeatures Trac is said to emphasize "ease of use and *low ceremony*". Can someone please explain what "ceremony" means in the context of software usage?

Comment: Sounds like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Low ceremony means a small amount of code to achieve something. It means you don't need to set up a lot of things in order to get going.

Comment: I encountered the term in a description of Kotlin as opposed to Java